# Как частично скрыть блок независимо от его размера?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сместить блок так что бы остался только заголовок. Как это сделать с учетом того, что заголовк и контент может быть разного размера?

Сейчас у меня только один вариант, сделать это через JS, получить размер заголовка и исходя из этого смещать его. Есть ли возможность сделать на CSS?

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block__body {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -100px;
}
.block:hover .block__body {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__body">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__body">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, eligendi soluta, iste delectus expedita, impedit reprehenderit iusto ipsum nemo fuga doloribus totam dolores aliquid numquam? Nihil culpa placeat expedita quibusdam!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.block {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .block__body {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .block__txt {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .block:hover .block__txt {
    height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__body">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__body">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, eligendi soluta, iste delectus expedita, impedit reprehenderit iusto ipsum nemo fuga doloribus totam dolores aliquid numquam? Nihil culpa placeat expedita quibusdam!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```